# Deep copy of array with elements containing an array?

Tags: swift, xcode, deep-copy

I'm trying to make a deep copy of a list of the following objects:

```
struct Book {
    var title: String
    var author: String
    var pages: Int
}

struct BookShelf {
    var number: Int
}

class BookShelfViewModel {
    var bookShelf: BookShelf

    var number: Int
    var books: [BookViewModel]?

    init(bookShelf: BookShelf) {
        self.bookShelf = bookShelf

        self.number = bookShelf.number
    }

    required init(original: BookShelfViewModel) {
        self.bookShelf = original.bookShelf

        self.number = original.number
    }
}

class BookViewModel {
    var book: Book

    var title: String
    var author: String
    var pages: Int

    init(book: Book) {
        self.book = book

        self.title = book.title
        self.author = book.author
        self.pages = book.pages
    }

    required init(original: BookViewModel) {
        self.book = original.book

        self.title = original.title
        self.author = original.author
        self.pages = original.pages
    }
}
```

Books for BookShelf is fetched in the BookShelfViewModel.

If I go like:

```
var copiedArray = originalArray

for bs in copiedArray {
   bs.books = bs.books.filter { $0.title == "SampleTitle" }
}
```

The above filter both the copiedArray and the originalArray, and I obviously just want the copiedArray altered.

When I clone the array like this:

```
var originalArray = [BookShelfViewModel]()
... // Fill the array
var clonedArray = originalArray.clone()
```

clonedArray is cloned, but clonedArray.books is empty.

I've created the extension and followed [this](https://gist.github.com/sohayb/4ba350f7e45c636cb3c9) gist. How do I clone the array in the objects in the array?

I've done a quick playground to visualize the problem, hopefully it helps understand what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: Array is a value type. Your implementation of `clone` is completely unnecessary. simply `let array2 = array1` makes a unique array.

Comment: You show us your implementation of `BookShelfViewModel` and `BookViewModel`, but then ask why `BookShelf` isn't properly copying its `books`... How about showing us your implementation of `BookShelf` instead of these view model objects?

Comment: Woops, my bad. I've changed it.

Comment: @Alexander Are you sure about that? I've added some testcode to my post.

Comment: It would help if you would show all of the necessary code that actually compiles; We don't have the `Book` or `Bookshelf` definitions and you show `originalArray` as a `let`, so you can't add objects to it.  Is `Book` a class or a struct?  See how to create a [MCVE]. Why does your `BookViewModel` extract the `Book` properties?  Why not make those properties computed variables that access the underlying `Book`'s properties?

Comment: @Paulw11 Book and BookShelf are structs. My BookViewModel will contain more for computed details for the view of the book, I just haven't added it yet. The let is my bad, I've corrected it.

Comment: @Recusiwe The arrays act unique, but the elements within them are still identical. You can easily make a copy with `let clonedBooks = books.map{ $0.clone }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your copying initialiser in `BookShelfViewModel` you don't actually clone the `books` array.  You need to add `self.books = original.books?.clone()` to `required init(original: BookShelfViewModel)`

```
class BookShelfViewModel: Copying {
    var bookShelf: BookShelf

    var number: Int
    var books: [BookViewModel]?

    init(bookShelf: BookShelf) {
        self.bookShelf = bookShelf

        self.number = bookShelf.number
    }

    required init(original: BookShelfViewModel) {
        self.bookShelf = original.bookShelf
        self.books = original.books?.clone()
        self.number = original.number
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I fetch the bookshelf from an API (I don't have any control over the API), and afterwards I fetch the Books from the API, based on the number on the bookshelf. And I like my models to match the API's.

Comment: Your answer did the job btw! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I get that, but then there is probably no reason to keep the original `BookShelf` object in the `BookShelfViewModel`, nor the original `Book` in the `BookViewModel`; those are just temporary objects that you use to get from the JSON to your model.